# function overload and type conversion resolution

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, type-conversion, overloading

why do we not see a "undefined call to overloaded function" error with the code bellow? just because int is a built in type? where in the standard can I find the guarantee for the conversion to built in type, such as in the code bellow?... thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
operator int(){ return 0; }
};

class A {
public:
A( int i ) { };
};

void f ( int i ) { cout << "overload f(int) was used!";};
void f ( A a )   { cout << "overload f(A) was used!" ;};


int main () {
  B b;
  f( b );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with A being directly constructible from B, by adding  `A::A(const B&)`?

Comment: By *undefined call to overload function*, do you mean *ambiguous*? Undefined errors trigger when the compiler matches a symbol but the linker does not find it.

Comment: @David yes, I meant "ambiguous". thank you.

Comment: @PiotrNcys: thats exactly what I was meaning to write in the first place,    A( B b ) { };   instead of  A( int i ) { }; - with this change, we do get the ambiguous error message I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with being a built-in type. You defined `operator int` for `B`. This means that you have provided a user-defined conversion from `B` to `int`. According to 12.3.4 of the standard, "at most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value." This is why it is not converted to `A`, because that would require two implicit conversions.

The rules for determining exactly when this happens are somewhat complicated, so many people advise that you avoid providing user-defined conversions. Another way of defining these is to provide a constructor with one argument; you can add `explicit` to the beginning to avoid it being applied implicitly.

When you call `f(b)`, the compiler applies the conversion that you provided to convert `b` to `int`. If you want to convert it to `A`, you'll have to define a conversion from `B` to `A`, or apply one of the conversions explicitly, like `f(int(b))` or `f(A(b))`.

Comment: ISO standard 12.3.4: "At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single
value."

Comment: ^ you should add this to the answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I was under the impression that this was if not basic just intermediate knowledge of the language... :) BTW, *presumptuous* is probably not the word you were looking for.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple: In C++11, you can mark the conversion operator `explicit` as well :)